How to use ed25519 in OpenVpn?
I want to use ed25519, so at first, in my server configuration file, I use this setting:
ecdh-curve ed25519

But in the log, it gives me this message:
WARNING: OpenSSL 3.0+ builds do not support specifying an ECDH curve with --ecdh-curve, using default curves. Use --tls-groups to specify groups

I don't know which is the default curve, and if it is better than ed25519.
Then I change the setting in the cofiguration file to this:
OpenSSL: error:0A080106:SSL routines::passed invalid argument:group 'ed25519' cannot be set

In this case the connection is not created.
So I read the OpenVpn help:
openvpn --show-groups

I get a list of curves/groups. But I don't see anyone that could be ed25519. In fact, it warns this:
Note this output does only list curves/groups that OpenSSL considers as
builtin EC curves. It does not list additional curves nor X448 or X25519

So I go the OpenSsl help:
openssl ecparam -list_curves

But in this case, I don't see any curve that could be ed25519.
In summary, I would like to know which is the name of the parameter that I should to use in OpenVpn ot can use ed25519.
Thanks.

Thanks. Also, seeing the client OpenVpn log, I can see that for the control channel it is used  ED25519, so it is used elliptic curve with X25519. It has sense, because when I create client certificate with EasyRSA, I configure it to use elliptic curve with this curve, so it is not needed to configure anything in OpenVpn, it knows from the certificate.
